# How to generate multiple message from a single message in spring xd?

Tags: spring-xd

How to achieve this with spring xd?

Input message : 
    {"key" : "temp", "key1" : "a b c"}

Output messages (my requirement):
    {"key" : "temp", "key1" : "a"}
{"key" : "temp", "key1" : "b"}
{"key" : "temp", "key1" : "c"}

[Note:I tried to use splitter but splitter is taking whole payload as input.]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to create a custom splitter module.

You could do it with a bunch of transformers followed by a splitter and more transformers but it would be rather convoluted...

```
jsonToMap->save key in a header->transform to key1.payload->split on space
     ->transform back to a map->add key entry back in->mapToJson
```